# Button Long Press Listener in Android jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am having an Android Composable UI with a `Button`.

How can I track button long press events? I got it working for the `Text` long press, but for `Button`, It is not working. Same way like below if I apply a modifier to the button, it is not working.

```
Text(
    text = view.text,
    fontSize = view.textFontSize.toInt().sp,
    fontWeight = FontWeight(view.textFontWeight.toInt()),
    color = Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor(view.textColor)),
    modifier = Modifier.clickable(
        onClick = {
            println("Single Click")
        }, 
        onLongClick = {
            println("Long Click")
        }, 
        onDoubleClick = {
            println("Double Tap")
        },
    ),
)
```

Comment: I think you can use LongPressFiredEvent but I'm not sure.

Comment: Button takes `InteractionSource` param by collecting it inside LaunchedEffect you can create a long click and click actions. You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77260577/5457853)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to roll your own `Button`. The Material `Button` is basically just a `Surface` and a `Row`. The reason adding your own `Modifier.clickable` doesn't work is because one is already set.

So, if you'd like to add `onLongPress`, etc you can copy/paste the default implementation and pass those lambdas in.

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class, ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
fun Button(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onLongClick: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    onDoubleClick: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    interactionState: InteractionState = remember { InteractionState() },
    elevation: ButtonElevation? = ButtonDefaults.elevation(),
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(),
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val contentColor by colors.contentColor(enabled)
    Surface(
        shape = shape,
        color = colors.backgroundColor(enabled).value,
        contentColor = contentColor.copy(alpha = 1f),
        border = border,
        elevation = elevation?.elevation(enabled, interactionState)?.value ?: 0.dp,
        modifier = modifier.combinedClickable(
            onClick = onClick,
            onDoubleClick = onDoubleClick,
            onLongClick = onLongClick,
            enabled = enabled,
            role = Role.Button,
            interactionState = interactionState,
            indication = null
        )
    ) {
        Providers(LocalContentAlpha provides contentColor.alpha) {
            ProvideTextStyle(
                value = MaterialTheme.typography.button
            ) {
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .defaultMinSizeConstraints(
                            minWidth = ButtonDefaults.MinWidth,
                            minHeight = ButtonDefaults.MinHeight
                        )
                        .indication(interactionState, rememberRipple())
                        .padding(contentPadding),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    content = content
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Button(
    onClick = {},
    onLongClick = {},
    onDoubleClick = {}
) {
    Text(text = "I'm a button")
}
```

Comment: I've implemented this in Material 3. It's not exactly the same as the normal button, but if not placed one next to the other, it's completelly normal.

Comment: Can you please provide a similar solution for `Card` as well. As, in Cards we need to modify the default `Card` and `Surface` implementation, as cards use a Surface under the hood and the click events are also on the Surface.

Answer (score 94):

You can use `combinedClickable` like the following:

```
Modifier
    .combinedClickable(
        onClick = { },
        onLongClick = { },
    )
```

Warning: with Compose `1.0.1` this method is marked as `@ExperimentalFoundationApi` so this answer may get outdated in the future releases.

Comment: Come on guys, simple and effective!

Comment: Not sure if this used to work but it doesn't anymore, seems like the button's own clickable modifier consumes the events before combinedClickable can get to it :( Why is something like this so difficult?

Comment: This modifier doesn't work for Buttons.

Answer (score 29):

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures  can be used as well.

for example:

```
 import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
 import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTapGestures

 modifier = Modifier
           .weight(2f)
           .pointerInput(Unit){
               detectTapGestures(
                     onLongPress = {
                             // perform some action here..
                     }
               )
            }
```

Comment: Doesn't work on a FAB

Answer (score 11):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures#tapping)

```
Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectTapGestures(
            onPress = { /* Called when the gesture starts */ },
            onDoubleTap = { /* Called on Double Tap */ },
            onLongPress = { /* Called on Long Press */ },
            onTap = { /* Called on Tap */ }
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

For some reasons it doesn't work with `Button`, but you can recreate button with `Card` composable and apply `combinedClickable` modifier to it.

```
ElevatedCard(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .padding(4.dp)
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
        .combinedClickable(
            interactionSource = remember {
                MutableInteractionSource()
            },
            indication = rememberRipple(bounded = true),
            onClick = onClick,
            onLongClick = onLongClick)
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        content()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class, ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onLongClick: () -> Unit = {},
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    elevation: ButtonElevation? = ButtonDefaults.elevation(),
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(),
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val contentColor by colors.contentColor(enabled)
    var tapped by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(shape)
            .indication(interactionSource, LocalIndication.current)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(
                onPress = { offset ->
                    tapped = true
                    val press = PressInteraction.Press(offset)
                    interactionSource.emit(press)
                    tryAwaitRelease()
                    interactionSource.emit(PressInteraction.Release(press))
                    tapped = false
                },
                onTap = { onClick() },
                onLongPress = { onLongClick() }
            )
        }
        ,
        shape = shape,
        color = colors.backgroundColor(enabled).value,
        contentColor = contentColor.copy(alpha = 1f),
        border = border,
        elevation = elevation?.elevation(enabled, interactionSource)?.value ?: 0.dp,
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides contentColor.alpha) {
            ProvideTextStyle(
                value = MaterialTheme.typography.button
            ) {
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .defaultMinSize(
                            minWidth = ButtonDefaults.MinWidth,
                            minHeight = ButtonDefaults.MinHeight
                        )
                        .padding(contentPadding),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    content = content
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Simply override default button and use it when you need to catch click or longClick event

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You can do it with passing InteractionSource and collecting it as

```
val context = LocalContext.current

val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

val viewConfiguration = LocalViewConfiguration.current


LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
    var isLongClick = false

    interactionSource.interactions.collectLatest { interaction ->
        when (interaction) {
            is PressInteraction.Press -> {
                isLongClick = false
                delay(viewConfiguration.longPressTimeoutMillis)
                isLongClick = true
                Toast.makeText(context, "Long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            is PressInteraction.Release -> {
                if (isLongClick.not()) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Button(
    onClick = {},
    interactionSource = interactionSource
) {
    Text("Some button")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

5 months later, the accepted answer doesn't work because of API changes. `detectTapGestures()` on `Button` didn't work for me either (i guess `.clickable()` steals the event?).

Surface now has two public constructors. First one is not clickable and explicitly overrides `.pointerInput(Unit)` to be empty

```
Surface(
...
    clickAndSemanticsModifier = Modifier
        .semantics(mergeDescendants = false) {}
        .pointerInput(Unit) { detectTapGestures { } }
)
```

Second one (that is used by `Button`) is clickable and explicitly sets  `Modifier.clickable()`. And if `Button` with `detectTapGestures()` doesn't work for you, this one won't work either.

There is a third private constructor that doesn't override your click events. So I ended up just stealing that and putting it next to custom LongPressButton.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun LongPressButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onClick: () -> Unit = {},
    onLongPress: () -> Unit = {},
    onDoubleClick: () -> Unit = {},
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    elevation: ButtonElevation? = ButtonDefaults.elevation(),
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(),
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val contentColor by colors.contentColor(enabled)
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier,
        shape = shape,
        color = colors.backgroundColor(enabled).value,
        contentColor = contentColor.copy(alpha = 1f),
        border = border,
        elevation = elevation?.elevation(enabled, interactionSource)?.value ?: 0.dp,
        clickAndSemanticsModifier = Modifier.combinedClickable(
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            indication = rememberRipple(),
            enabled = enabled,
            role = Role.Button,
            onClick = onClick,
            onDoubleClick = onDoubleClick,
            onLongClick = onLongPress,
        )
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides contentColor.alpha) {
            ProvideTextStyle(
                value = MaterialTheme.typography.button
            ) {
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .defaultMinSize(
                            minWidth = ButtonDefaults.MinWidth,
                            minHeight = ButtonDefaults.MinHeight
                        )
                        .padding(contentPadding),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    content = content
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
private fun Surface(
    modifier: Modifier,
    shape: Shape,
    color: Color,
    contentColor: Color,
    border: BorderStroke?,
    elevation: Dp,
    clickAndSemanticsModifier: Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val elevationOverlay = LocalElevationOverlay.current
    val absoluteElevation = LocalAbsoluteElevation.current + elevation
    val backgroundColor = if (color == MaterialTheme.colors.surface && elevationOverlay != null) {
        elevationOverlay.apply(color, absoluteElevation)
    } else {
        color
    }
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalContentColor provides contentColor,
        LocalAbsoluteElevation provides absoluteElevation
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier
                .shadow(elevation, shape, clip = false)
                .then(if (border != null) Modifier.border(border, shape) else Modifier)
                .background(
                    color = backgroundColor,
                    shape = shape
                )
                .clip(shape)
                .then(clickAndSemanticsModifier),
            propagateMinConstraints = true
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

If there is a better way that works, please share. Because current solution is ugly.

Comment: Not working now

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69156624/onpressin-and-onpressout-in-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 1):

I tried @adneal answer and for some reason it wouldn't pick up the "onLongClick".

After some research I updated as follow to make it work :

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class, androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ButtonWithLongPress(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    onDoubleClick:()->Unit = {},
    onLongClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    elevation: ButtonElevation? = ButtonDefaults.elevation(),
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(),
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val contentColor by colors.contentColor(enabled)
Surface(
    onClick = { },
    modifier = modifier
        .combinedClickable(
            interactionSource,
        rememberRipple(),
        true,
        null,
        Role.Button,
        null,
        onClick = { onClick() },
        onLongClick = { onLongClick() },
        onDoubleClick = {onDoubleClick()}),
    enabled = enabled,
    shape = shape,
    color = colors.backgroundColor(enabled).value,
    contentColor = contentColor.copy(alpha = 1f),
    border = border,
    elevation = elevation?.elevation(enabled, interactionSource)?.value ?: 0.dp,
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides contentColor.alpha) {
        ProvideTextStyle(
            value = MaterialTheme.typography.button
        ) {
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .defaultMinSize(
                        minWidth = ButtonDefaults.MinWidth,
                        minHeight = ButtonDefaults.MinHeight
                    )
                    .padding(contentPadding)
                    .combinedClickable(interactionSource,
                        null,
                        true,
                        null,
                        Role.Button,
                        null,
                        onClick = { onClick() },
                        onLongClick = { onLongClick() },
                        onDoubleClick = { onDoubleClick() }),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                content = content
            )
        }
    }
}}
```

Now it works the way it should, and setting up a double-click is optional if necessary

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done it is making a button via a Canvas and with the modifiers give the canvas the LongClick functionality, keep in mind that a Click action is necessary, altough you can leave it empty. Hope this solution helps.

```
    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun LongPressButton(runViewModel: RunActivityScreenViewModel, context: Context) {
        var actionState by remember { mutableStateOf(ActivityState.PLAY) }
        val buttonColorPlay = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
        val buttonColorStop = MaterialTheme.colors.secondaryVariant
        val shadow = Color.Black.copy(.5f)
        val stopIcon: ImageBitmap = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.stop_icon)
        val playIcon: ImageBitmap = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.play_icon)
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .combinedClickable(
                    interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource(),
                    onClick = {
                       // Your Click Action
                    },
                    onLongClick = {
                       // Your Long Press Action
                    },
                    indication = rememberRipple(
                        bounded = false,
                        radius = 20.dp,
                        color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
                    ),
                ),
        ) {
            drawCircle(
                color = shadow,
                radius = 100f,
                center = Offset(
                    center.x + 2f,
                    center.y + 2f
                )
            )
            drawCircle(
                color = buttonColorStop,
                radius = 100f
            )
            scale(scale = 2.5f) {
                drawImage(
                    image = stopIcon,
                    topLeft = Offset(
                        center.x - (stopIcon.width / 2),
                        center.y - (stopIcon.width / 2)
                    ),
                    alpha = 1f,
                )
            }
        }
    }
```