# Long-press event on IconToggleButton

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-touch-event

I have a toggle button. It works fine, but I want to be able to long-press it.

```
      IconToggleButton(
            checked = isChecked,
            onCheckedChange = onCheck,
            modifier = modifier
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures(
                        onLongPress = {
                            showingHelpDialog = true
                        }
                    )
                } 
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = if (isChecked) {
                    Icons.Filled.Star
                } else {
                    Icons.Filled.StarBorder
                },
                contentDescription = null,
            )
        }
```

This doesn't work, because `IconToggleButton` itself overrides `pointerInput` through the `toggleable` modifier.

I *could* copy all the source code from `IconToggleButton`/`toggleable` and hack in my own `pointerInput`. But that would require me to copy a lot of low-level component logic which I expressly *don't* want to copy into my own source code, because it should be part of the Material library and I want to benefit from potential improvements in the Material library.

Is there another way I could listen for long-press events?

Comment: You can try to do the long press detection on a box around IconToggleButton or on the Icon.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65835642/button-long-press-listener-in-android-jetpack-compose

Comment: I don't want the toggle interaction to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
modifier.pointerInput(Unit) { /*...*/ }
```

use

```
modifier.combinedClickable(
        onLongClick = { /*....*/ },
        onClick ={ /*....*/ })
```