How to fix that LazyColumn always swallows mouse clicks, even when no items are visible?
I have this code and I want to always display an area which displays notifications in a corner of the window. Here, I have the issue that LazyColumn always swallows any clicks, regardless if any items are displayed or not, and I can not find a way to disable this click swallowing. Since I want clicks to only register on the LazyColumn on displayed items, not on the entire content.
The reason I would like to use a LazyColumn is because of its .animateItem() functionality, which animates item placement. I removed .fillMaxHeight() from the LazyColumn, but then the height is not properly animated on item changes, and it does not animate nicely with .animateItem().
Note
There can be any kind of nested Composables displayed in the first Row, it won't just be this one Row. I am using this code to display a global notification area which is displayed above everything else.

Alternatively, I found out that using Column with AnimatedVisibility works fine, but it complicates the notification visibility code and I have slight issues dismissing notifications in order that way, since I launch one LaunchedEffect(Unit) per notification this way, so I would rather not do it that way.

import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.singleWindowApplication

fun main() = singleWindowApplication {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clickable {
                    println("clicked")
                }
        ) {
        }
        Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.DarkGray)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .width(300.dp)
            ) {
                items(listOf("a", "b", "c")) {
                    Text(it, modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(10.dp)
                        .clickable {
                            println("clicked text")
                        })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Why do you want assign clickable to sibling instead of parent Box? Gestures propagate from child to parent by default and with some changes you can change propagation direction from parent to child but i don't think propagating from one child to another is possible with Jetpack Compose gesture system with pointerInput.

However you can mimic it being clicked with MutableInteractionSource if you add clickable to Box. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78951692/5457853. You can also check gestures in Jetpack Compose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64571945/how-can-i-get-ontouchevent-in-jetpack-compose/70847531#70847531

Valid points for my trivial code example. The first Row can contain any kind of nested Composables, I am trying to implement a notification area (as you see in top right of macOS) and anything can be displayed below, practically. Your code examples assumes that interactionSourceParent can be set which won't be the case for me. (I edited my post to reflect that)

May i ask why you can't set MutableInteractionSource for child? If you can expose a Modifier to set clickable, which you should always define Composble with Modifiers param, you can invoke event on child when parent is clicked. Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77260577/5457853 Instead of child onClick you can collect and invoke events accordingly.

And if this is also not possible another option is to write a gesture for click in parent that also gets bounds of notification panel it gets as Rect via onGloballyPositioned  then if parent received touch in that bound invoke click action for Row or notification area.

Basically you can invoke action in parent, get notification area bounds and invoke action that notification panel supposed to do if touch is in that bounds. And to invoke indication you will need to set indication(parentMutableSource) that implements custom gesture.

If assigning click gesture to parent and invoking action for child is an option i can provide a solution.

I'd love to see a solution, maybe this is easier than I think it is. Can you show me how to assign the click gesture to the parent and then trigger for any item in the LazyColumn on its position?
